# how to create a dialog like true caller when call ends in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I want to create a dialog like the true caller when call ends in android[image]. My try till now is that I created an activity and then called a custom dialog but its kind of ugly and also the activity is shown behind the dialog even if I am not seting the contentView with setContentView().